# Bending of a spline

Tags: potential-energy

The introduction section on [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) states: "the spline will take a shape that minimizes the bending", while showing the formula for curvature of a real curve.

Question is, what is the formula for the bending that is to be minimized, the curvature is a function rather than a number?! Is it some integral or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stored energy in a spline goes as the inverse square of the radius of curvature - so if you want to minimize the energy, you want to minimize

$$\int \frac{ds}{r(s)^2}$$

where $s$ is taken along the length of the spline, and $r$ is the local radius of curvature.

Comment: How come the integral result in a number with unit $m^{-1}$, shouldn't it be joule?

Comment: @Coolwater Floris has left off the constant pre-factors; so what he is computing there is harmonic mean of the radius of curvature along the path. To figure out the pre-factor you need examine the simple cases of bending an arc of constant radius of curvature.

Comment: @dmckee is right, I did not write an equation for the energy; I said "if you want to minimize the energy, you want to minimize" [this equation].  Minimizing the integral can happen regardless of the units or scale factors. Put differently - as written the integral does not evaluate to the energy, but it _scales with_ the energy stored. Minimize one, and you minimize the other.